# How do I mark dnf package as removed?

Tags: fedora, package-management, rpm, dnf

I want to remove `dnf` installed packages using pip but when I type:

```
$ dnf info package
```

the package manager wrongly shows that the package is installed. I alternatively tried removing the package using `dnf remove package` but it wants to remove dozens of dependencies.

I have looked at `dnf mark install` and `dnf mark remove` but metadata about these commands are not clear.

How do I mark system packages that have been uninstalled by pip so that `dnf` also knows they have been removed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about this wrongly. There are many applications that are part of the distro that require `python`, `pip`, and a whole host of Python modules.

The installation of these packages into `/usr/bin` is the domain of 1 package manager (`dnf` - on Fedora, `yum` on CentOS). You should not be using `pip` to install/uninstall anything into this directory. Doing so puts your ability to properly manage the system at risk.

#### From this point you have:

1. Only use `dnf` to manage `python-*` packages

   ```
   $ yum search python |& grep ^python | head
   python-Bottleneck-doc.noarch : Documentation files for python-Bottleneck
   python-CDDB.x86_64 : CDDB and FreeDB audio CD track info access in Python
   python-GeoIP.x86_64 : Python bindings for the GeoIP geographical lookup
   python-GeographicLib.noarch : Python implementation of GeographicLib
   python-GnuPGInterface.noarch : A Python module to interface with GnuPG
   python-GridDataFormats.noarch : Read and write data on regular grids in Python
   python-IPy.noarch : Python module for handling IPv4 and IPv6 Addresses and
   python-Levenshtein.x86_64 : Python extension computing string distances and
   python-MAPI.x86_64 : The Python MAPI extension by Zarafa
   python-NLopt.x86_64 : Python bindings for NLopt
   ```
2. Setup a dedicated version of Python/pip using `virtualenv`/`pipenv` for your personal software development activities on these systems.

   Fight the urge and leave these intact and not view them as there for you to use etc. for your software endeavors. For your applications you should be using something like `virtualenv` or `pipenv` to setup & maintain your own `reqirements.txt` files and your own isolated Python environments where you'll install/maintain/manage your coding project's needed Python modules.

   We have extensive Q&A on the installation/setup of `virtualenv` on the site already so please use these to find out more on anything specific to it.

   For reference please refer to these tutorials on getting started with `virtualenv`:

   - [Pipenv & Virtual Environments](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/)
   - [A non-magical introduction to Pip and Virtualenv for Python beginners](https://www.dabapps.com/blog/introduction-to-pip-and-virtualenv-python/)